# How to pass intent to broadcast receiver and start service Android

Tags: java, android, service, alarmmanager, handler

*Java Target API 30, Min API 19*

I have alarms that are created by a Handler thread inside my foreground service.
I have alarms that that are set in the handler based on user inputs. I can confirm that the time being passed to the alarms are correct. Here is the alarm object class:

```
public class StartAlarmObject  {
    private String name;
    private Context context;
    private int index;
    private int day;
    private long time;
    private NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager;
    private ArrayList<RestrictionObject> restrictions = new ArrayList<>();
    private ReadAndWriteRestrictions readAndWriteRestrictions = new ReadAndWriteRestrictions();
    private AlarmManager alarmManager;
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    public StartAlarmObject (String name, Context context, int index, int day, long time)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.context = context;
        this.index = index;
        this.day = day;
        this.time = time;
    }

    public void startAlarm() {
        System.out.println("starting alarm/alarm setting...");
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlertReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra("index", index);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, (index * 100) + (day * 10), intent, 0);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pendingIntent);
                System.out.println("setting exact and allowing while idle");
            } else {
                alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pendingIntent);
                System.out.println("setting exact");
                }
        } else {
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, pendingIntent);
            System.out.println("just setting");
        }
    }

    public void cancelAlarm()
    {
        if (alarmManager!= null) {
            alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        }
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

I get the "setting exact and allowing while idle" println statements I expect, but I never see any reaction from the broadcast receiver class I pass the intent to:

```
package com.example.gotimejavaversion;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class AlertReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        System.out.println("alert received");
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(App.getContext(), TheRestrictor.class);
        serviceIntent.putExtra("caller", "alarm");
        System.out.println("The alarm reached the receiver");
        context.stopService(serviceIntent);
        context.startService(serviceIntent);
    }
}
```

What do I need in order to reach the broadcast receiver or restart the service when the alarm goes off?
Hopefully I'm just missing something simple.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have the receiver registered in the manifest?

Comment: Yes, I do. I maxed its priority just in case as well, but it seemed to have no effect. `        <receiver android:name=".AlertReceiver"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:priority="999">
        </receiver>`